# Ajax Обновление количества товара после добавление товара?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Мне нужно сделать обновление количества товара в input после того как я указал в другом input количества товара которого мне нужно купить.

код input которого нужно обновлять:

```
woocommerce_quantity_input( $args = array( 'input_value'   =>  erd_get_cnt_products( $product->id ) ) );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так делайте, раз нужно, в чем проблема?

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov так я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Подразумевается, что тот кто задает вопрос, уже что то пытался сделать.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov Да пытался но не выходит написать обработчик в консоли выдаёт ошибку. в Ajax я полный нуб.

    var data = '';
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/ajaxkolvo.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
  
   $( ".post-<?php echo $post->ID ?> input.qty").val(data); 
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
   $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {'type': 'AJAX'},
                beforeSend: function (request) {},
                success: function (result) {
                    Находишь тут свой input при помощи jQ и вставляешь пришедшие данные
                },
                complete: function(){},
                error: function(jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
}, interval);
```

`interval` - через сколько времени запускать функцию. в миллисекундах. 1000 - 1 секунда.

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите, для каких целей используете ajax, что делаете на стороне php? 
Если Вам нужно обновить поле из инпута другого поля сделайте так:

```
$(".input1").on('change',function{ // Ждете каждое изменение поля №1
    var input1_val = $(".input1").val().trim(); // Записываете значение поля, если необходимо
    $(".input2").html(input1_val); // Вставляете записанное значение в поле №2  
});
```